# Writing a macro such that static is disabled when testing

Tags: c, ceedling

I am having trouble writing this macro. I am using ceedling.

I have a file, "globals.h", which has the following code:

```
#ifndef globals
    #ifndef UNITY
        #define STATIC static
    #else
        #define STATIC
    #endif
    #define globals 1
#endif
```

So, what should happen here is that any method which uses STATIC will be static if the code is not being tested with unity, else it will be not static.

My test file includes "unity.h", and then includes "globals.h", and then includes "protocol.h".

The file being tested, "protocol.c", includes "globals.h" and then "protocol.h".

The test file, "test_protocol.c", includes "unity.h", then "globals.h", then "protocol.h".

From my understanding, UNITY should be defined first, then it will go to `globals.h`, and define STATIC as nothing, since UNITY has been defined already in UNITY.h

However, the behavior I am seeing is that no matter what I do, I cannot get `globals.h` to enter that `#else` directive, and so it appears to be impossible to have `STATIC` be defined as anything other than `static`.

However, I know that what i am trying to accomplish is possible, because many people recommend this strategy and have implemented it. So, what am I doing that is causing `globals.h` to think that UNITY is not defined, when it is?

Comment: The explanation of what is in which file is hard to follow.  Can you create specific minimal files that demonstrate the problem?

Comment: does `unity.h` actually define `UNITY`?

Answer (score 0):

`test_protocol.c` doesn't need to include `globals.h` file.
The point of view from `test_protocol.c` is that everything in `protocol.c` has external linkage, but itself doesn't need that.

Because `protocol.c` and `test_protocol.c` are in different translation unit, `UNITY`  defined in `UNITY.h` is not seen in `protocol.c` because it doesn't include `UNITY.h`.

Of course, the code under test must be kept intact. So we must somehow tell `protocol.c` about `UNITY` flag during the test but not in the normal compilation. That is where the section `:defines:` in the yaml file shines.

The `project.yml` file has already defined a `TEST` macro:

```
:defines:
  # in order to add common defines:
  #  1) remove the trailing [] from the :common: section
  #  2) add entries to the :common: section (e.g. :test: has TEST defined)
  :common: &common_defines []
  :test:
    - *common_defines
    - TEST                      # <--- here
  :test_preprocess:
    - *common_defines
    - TEST                      # <--- and here
```

You need to define `UNITY` in here too or just use the `TEST` macro in your `globals.h`.
The `TEST` macros are there for this purpose anyway.

This ensures the flag `TEST` is passed to every translation unit if it is compiled by `ceedling` for testing, but not there if you use the normal compiler as usual.